# CAGradientLayer not draw the gradient correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cagradientlayer

I use CAShapeLayer to draw a circle and set it as the mask of CAGradientLayer, here is the code:

```
CAShapeLayer *circleShapeLayer = [CAShapelayer new];
// draw circle path code here...

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                         (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
// self here means a UIView
gradientLayer.mask = circleShapeLayer;
gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
[self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

When I run the app, it will display a gradient circle, but the gradient is strange.

What I want is a circle that at start point, the color is white and at end point the color is clear color, it should look like this:

[image]

But the color of the circle in the Simulator screen is:

[image]

The color is symmetric.

I think the problem is that I do not set the `gradientLayer.colors` correctly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448618/cagradientlayer-showing-as-solid-color/5449257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAGradientLayer can not paint gradient along an arc. on the other hand, the mask layer's frame is too small than gradient layer's frame to see clear color

Answer (score 0):

To Umair's response, it didn't make sense to me at first because even `whiteColor` or `blackColor` is being fetched by `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` but then I read this in the documentation:

> When rendered, the colors are mapped to the output color space before being interpolated.

So maybe this is really it:

```
gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,
                         (__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

@J.Hunter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761906/4577897) is correct in that `CAGradientLayer`s cannot draw along an arc. This means that your drawn gradients will be limited to **[radial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/RadialGradient.png)** and **[linear](http://www.imagemagick.org/image/gradients/linear_gradient.png)**. You are specifically looking to create an **[angled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/ConicalGradient_angle1.png)** gradient, which I've attempted to do in the past as well.

Unfortunately, `CAGradientLayer` is bound to these limitations, and the best way I've found to create a masked angled gradient is to mask with a `UIImage` that contains an angled gradient. This won't be nearly as dynamic as drawing your own gradient, but it seems to be the best (possibly only) option at the moment.